# Como usar select em uma tabela que não está relacionada?

Tags: mysql, select

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso construir uma consulta SQL que liste o
valor a pagar por cada km, a quantidade
de km utilizado e o valor total a pagar por
cada locação

É um exercicio de SELECT e inner/left join mas não sei como relacionar LOCACAO com TABELA.

Obrigado!

Comment: Mas a tabela está relacionada. `LOCACAO > VEICULO > TABELA_VEICULO > TABELA`. Basta entender como cada uma se relaciona e fazer teus JOINS.

Answer (score -1):

Vou tentar te ajudar pelo o que eu entendi da sua pergunta. Em banco de dados temos o conceito de chave primaria e chave estrangeira, chave primaria é um identificador único de um registro de uma tabela. Já a chave estrangeira é uma referencia a chave primaria de outra tabela. Tendo uma noção básica disso você pode relacionar tabelas diferentes através das chaves primarias e chaves estrangeiras. E para ajudar com a parte dos inner joins vou deixar o link do w3schools https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp